# How to use brackets in laravel query builder in 'where' clause?

Tags: sql, database, laravel, where-clause, brackets

I am new at laravel and i am having problems with its query builder  . I am running this code

```php
return DB::table('t_chat')
    ->where('chat_msg_from', '=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->where('chat_msg_to', '=', $to_id)
    ->orWhere('chat_msg_from', '=', $to_id)
    ->where('chat_msg_to', '=', auth()->user()->id)
    ->get();
```

this code will run query like :

```sql
SELECT * FROM t_chat WHERE chat_msg_to = 2 AND chat_msg_from = 1 
OR
chat_msg_to = 1 AND chat_msg_from = 2
```

But I want it like :

```sql
SELECT * FROM t_chat WHERE (chat_msg_to = 2 AND chat_msg_from = 1) 
OR
(chat_msg_to = 1 AND chat_msg_from = 2)
```

Comment: Note that you don't need any extra brackets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch:

```php
DB::table('t_chat')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->where('chat_mgs_to', '=', 2)
        ->Where('chat_mgs_from', '=', 1);
    })
    ->orWhere(function ($query) {
        $query->where('chat_mgs_to', '=', 1)
        ->Where('chat_mgs_from', '=', 2);
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

This way you can add conditions in query:

```
return DB::table('t_chat')
->where('chat_msg_from', '=', auth()->user()->id)
->where('chat_msg_to', '=', $to_id)
->orWhere(function($q) {
     $q->where('chat_msg_from', '=', $to_id)
       ->Where('chat_msg_to', '=', auth()->user()->id);
     })
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [whereRaw](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-methods) in laravel queries:

```
return DB::table('t_chat')->whereRaw("(chat_msg_from=auth()->user()->id 
   and chat_msg_to=$to_id) or (chat_msg_from=$to_id and chat_msg_to =
    auth()->user()->id)")->get();
```